# Persistent user profile on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi, flask

I am building a GAE application with flask and gae-sessions (built-in flask sessions are just so confusing to work with).

**What's the best way to add persistent profiles?**

I'm currently extending gaesessions.Session to add @werkzeug.cached_property profile. This way profile is loaded lazily and persisted after each request. It works but seems like I'm reinventing the wheel. Any existing libraries or frameworks already do anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Flask-Security](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Security/) is probably the most mature library to do that, and is under active development at the moment of writing.

Answer (score 0):

[Builtin flask sessions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#sessions) works with a cookie it's should be ok if you don't plan to store a lot of data.

GAE Session is usable as is you shouldn't have to add anything for it to work, its handled by the underlying framework.

Comment: By persistent profiles I mean storing user accounts in the datastore. Sessions are not supposed to be shared across multiple devices/browsers, nor expected to survive clearing the cookies